# distribute values equally from one dataframe to another based on text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two data-frames like below

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

random = np.random.RandomState(seed=123)

columns = ['Assessment Type', 'Weight %']

assessment = ['Mid-Term', 'Quiz', 'Final Exam', 'Assignment']

wight = [30, 20, 35, 15]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([assessment, wight]),
                           columns=columns)

df1['Weight %'] = df1['Weight %'].apply(int)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(random.randint(0, 100, size=(4, 8)), columns=list('ABCDEFGH'))

df2.iloc[0, :] = ['', 'Mid-Term', 'Quiz', 'Mid-Term', 'Quiz', '', 'Final Exam', '']
df2.iloc[1, :] = ['' for i in range(df2.columns.size)]
```

`df1` =

```
  Assessment Type  Weight %
0        Mid-Term        30
1            Quiz        20
2      Final Exam        35
3      Assignment        15
```

`df2` =

```
    A         B     C         D     E   F           G   H
0      Mid-Term  Quiz  Mid-Term  Quiz      Final Exam
1
2  78        36    96        80    68  49          55  67
3   2        84    39        66    84  47          61  48
```

I want to distribute the grade weight from `df1` equally between the same grade assessment type in `df2`

The desired output for the case above is as below.

```
    A         B     C         D     E   F           G   H
0      Mid-Term  Quiz  Mid-Term  Quiz      Final Exam
1            15    10        15    10              35
2  78        36    96        80    68  49          55  67
3   2        84    39        66    84  47          61  48
```

Could someone please help to achieve this in pandas.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
type_counts = df2.loc[0].value_counts().drop('').rename("type_counts")
distributor = df1.set_index("Assessment Type").join(type_counts)
distributor["alocated weight"] = distributor["Weight %"].div(distributor["type_counts"])
df2.loc[1] = df2.loc[0].map(distributor["alocated weight"]).fillna('')
print(df2)
```

result:

```
    A         B     C         D     E   F           G   H
0      Mid-Term  Quiz  Mid-Term  Quiz      Final Exam    
1            15    10        15    10              35    
2  78        36    96        80    68  49          55  67
3   2        84    39        66    84  47          61  48
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do it would be to map the row 0 values using a dictionary of assessments and weights to your row 1 (the one you want filled with the actual weights).

I imagine the solution would look something like this

```
assess_weights = dict(zip(assessment,wight))
df2.iloc[1,:] = df2.iloc[0,:].map(assess_weights)
```

Comment: This solution does not distribute weights equally, instead, all are given the total weight.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.

```
series = df2.loc[0]
series = series.groupby(series).count()

assess_weights = dict(zip(assessment,wight))

a1 = df2.loc[0].map(series)
a2 = df2.loc[0].map(assess_weights)

row_value = a2.div(a1).fillna('')

df2.loc[1] = row_value

print(df2)
```